# Renaming Columns based on values in first row

Tags: sas

I have a data set like this:

```
DATA HAVE;
   INPUT A $ B $ C $ D $  ;
   DATALINES;
VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4
cat dog cat dog
dog cat cat dog
dog cat cat cat
;
RUN;
```

and I want to transform that data set to resemble this:

```
DATA WANT;
   INPUT VAR1 $ VAR2 $ VAR3 $ VAR4 $  ;
   DATALINES;
cat dog cat dog
dog cat cat dog
dog cat cat cat
;
RUN;
```

Is there a function I can apply to accomplish this? Basically, I want to rename the columns to the corresponding values in row 1, as well as remove row 1.

To give a little context to this odd request, I am importing an awkwardly formatted xls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the values from the first row to generate a set of OLD=NEW values that you can use in a RENAME statement or RENAME= option.

```
proc transpose data=have(obs=1) out=names ;
  var _all_;
run;
```

If the list is short enough you can do it with a single macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select catx('=',_name_,col1) 
    into :rename separated by ' '
    from names
  ;
quit;
```

Then you can use the macro variable.

```
data want ;
  set have (firstobs=2 rename=(&rename));
run;
```

Comment: Frickin' nifty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `proc transpose` and any of the first row's values happen to be more than 32 characters in length, they will be invalid variable names when used in the `rename`.

So, an alternative to `proc transpose` is to use arrays and array functions to build your rename list.

```
data cols ;
  set have (obs=1) ;
  array vars{*} $32. _CHARACTER_ ;
  do nvar = 1 to dim(vars) ;
    curr_varname = vname(vars{nvar}) ; /* get the current variable name, e.g. A B etc */
    new_varname = vars{nvar} ; /* variable value, e.g. VAR1 VAR2 etc */
    output ;
  end ;
run ;
```

Then follow the same method as Tom to get the old/new pairs into a macro variable to embed in a `rename=(...)` statement.

```
proc sql ;
  select catx('=',curr_varname,new_varname) into :RENAMELIST separated by ' '
  from cols ;
quit ;

data want ;
  set have (firstobs=2 rename=(&RENAMELIST)) ;
run ;
```